# PHP ftp_login fails even with correct credentials

Tags: php, ftp

I'm attempting an FTP login via PHP with this code:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect('XXX.XX.XXX.XXX') or die("Could not connect");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'USER', 'PASS');
var_dump($login);
```

But I keep getting this error:

> ftp_login(): Login or password incorrect!

However, I can successfully use these credentials with an FTP program such as FileZilla. Are my credentials actually wrong?

Any ideas?

FileZilla log file:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to Claytons FTPS
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Using authentication type TLS
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER alfresco
Response:   331 Password required for alfresco
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   230 Logged on
```

FileZilla log file with disabled encryption:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to Claytons FTPS
Command:    USER alfresco
Response:   331 This server does not allow plain FTP. You have to use FTP over TLS.
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   530 Login or password incorrect!
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your FileZilla logs show, your FTP server does not allow unencrypted connection.

```
Response:   331 This server does not allow plain FTP. You have to use FTP over TLS.
```

Unfortunately PHP hides away that error message and propagates only an irrelevant response to `PASS` command.

---

You have to use [`ftp_ssl_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) instead of plain `ftp_connect`:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect('XXX.XX.XXX.XXX') or die("Could not connect");
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks mate!